# Symfony SyncTransport dispatches twice

Tags: symfony, symfony6, symfony-messenger

I don't know if it's a bug or feature or concept that I don't get at the moment, so please enlighten me.

```
public function send(Envelope $envelope): Envelope
{
    /** @var SentStamp|null $sentStamp */
    $sentStamp = $envelope->last(SentStamp::class);
    $alias = null === $sentStamp ? 'sync' : ($sentStamp->getSenderAlias() ?: $sentStamp->getSenderClass());

    $envelope = $envelope->with(new ReceivedStamp($alias));

    return $this->messageBus->dispatch($envelope);
}
```

Above is the send method of Symfony's Messenger Component's SyncTransport class.
If I explicity set a route for a message class to sync, like

```
framework:
  messenger:
    transports:
      sync: "sync://"
    routing: 
      App\TestMessage:   sync
```

and now dispatch the message to a bus, it will traverse the bus and all middlewares which might add stamps.
Now before the handler takes action, the sync transport will dispatch the message to the same bus again and middlewares execute again (in my case adding the same stamps again (this is where I spotted something feels not right)).

If I remove the line

```
App\TestMessage:   sync
```

the described behavior won't happen, no double stamps and no second dispatch on the bus, just the handler will be executed.

So the question is, is this wanted, did I miss a concept here or might this be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why symfony devs made sync transport this way but removing routing to sync transport will fix this strange behaviour.

Also if you have routing to any async transport and you want to use `TransportNamesStamp` to handle command synchronously, you can not just use

```php
Envelope::wrap($envelope, [new TransportNamesStamp(['sync])]);
```

because you will face the same issue like you described.
Instead you can handle it this way:

```php
Envelope::wrap($envelope, [new TransportNamesStamp([])]);
```

by passing empty array of transports. `SendMessageMiddleware` will just execute next handler instead of whole new command via message bus.